# GIT SVN Externals Url Directory Order

Tags: git, svn, svn-externals

I'm using GIT-SVN at work because i've used GIT extensively and like the ability to do local branches on my own machine. With that being said, They are also using svn externals at my job to handle shared library components. I do not have control over anything I have stated thus far.

I have a script that will pull down externals and clone them and create links. Works great on Repositories that I primarily control. However, most of the rest of the company is using TurtoiseSVN and it appears that it sets the externals order differently.

for instance..

{revision if any} {url} {subdirectory}

where as.. the script uses git svn show-externals to find the externals which expects the order to be:

{subdirectory} {revision if any} {url}

The commandline version of subversion doesn't care with either approach.

Why are there differences on this?

Comment: Right after I posted this.. I found this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html which states the format turtoise is using is the "new" format.. I guess show-externals is updated to support this yet.

Comment: You should post this solution as an answer (yes, you can and are encouraged to answer your own questions).

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted this.. I found this: svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html which states the format turtoise is using is the "new" format.. I guess show-externals is updated to support this yet.